# Prove that an uncountable set with the cofinite topology is Fréchet–Urysohn

Tags: general-topology

A space $X$ is said to be Fréchet–Urysohn give that,

$$x\in \overline{A} \text { if and only if there is a sequence } \langle x_n \rangle \text{ in } A \text{ such that } \langle x_n \rangle\to x.$$

---

**Lemma A:** Let $X$ be any uncountable set with the cofinite topology. Let $x\in X$ and $\langle x_n \rangle$ a sequence in $X$. Then $\langle x_n \rangle$ converges to $x$ if and only if for every $y\neq x$ we have $x_n=y$ for only finitely many $n\in\Bbb N$.

Using **Lemma A**, how can I prove that $X$, an uncountable set with the cofinite topology, is Fréchet–Urysohn?

---

I know that if $A\subseteq X$ is finite then $\overline{A}=A$, whereas if $A\subseteq X$ is infinite then $\overline{A}=X$.

Comment: lemma A is not really needed, it's simpler than that.

Answer (score 1):

... so if $\lvert A\rvert\ge\aleph_0$, then consider an injective sequence $x_\bullet:\Bbb N\to A$: that sequence converges to every point of $X$ by the lemma.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is finite, and $x \in X$ we have two cases: $x \notin A$, then $X\setminus A$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ that misses all of $A$, so no sequence from $A$ can converge to $x$.
If $x \in A$, a constant sequence will show already that $x$ *is* a sequential limit from $A$. So $A$ equals the set of sequential limits from $A$, and also this equals $\overline{A}$.

If $A$ is infinite, and $x \in X$, then *any* sequence fom $A$ that has all terms distinct (this can be done easily  when $A$ is infinite) converges to $x$. (Lemma A is not really needed for this, it's an easy observation). So $X$ equals the set of all sequential lmits from $A$ and this is also $\overline{A}$.

So in all cases sequential closure of $A$ is closure of $A$ and $X$ is Fréchet-Urysohn.